# There exists an integer with alternating digits $1$ and $2$ which is divisible by $2013$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math, problem-solving

Could someone give me **hints** in how to solve the following (rather interesting) problem?

> Prove that there exists an integer consisting of an alternance of $1$s
>   and $2$s with as many $1$s as $2$s (as in $12$, $1212$, $1212121212$, etc.), and
>   which is divisible by $2013$.

**Source:** Problem 4 [in this document](http://www.math.washington.edu/~putnam/HW1.pdf).

I just had to ask it before 2013 ends :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Among the first 2014 numbers of this kind, two must have the same remainder mod $2013$.

Comment: Just brilliant. Many thanks :)

Comment: This is formally known as http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle

Comment: Actual solution can be obtained by Fermat's theorem. It is 12 repeated 660 times. I *had* to answer before 2013 ended :-)

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

Consider the numbers: the sequence of integers $12,1212,121212,12121212,.......$

Two of them must be equal modulo $2013$.Hence, the difference of these two must be divisible by $2013$. Now use this difference to obtain the desired number (note that $2,5\not|2013$)

Comment: Thanks for more detailed explanation :D

Answer (score 1):

note $3$ has to divide the number. So what can you say about the sum of the digits?

$11 has to divide the number. So what can you say about the sum of digits in the odd location and even location.

Once you have fixed these two, you want $61$ divide the number.

I am glad that 2013 is not a prime number :)

---

In response to the comment by OP:

Suppose the number starts as $12$. It is not clear if the length has to be even, but I will assume that. Then every time you add another $12$ you are muliplying  by 100 and adding 12.
So
$$
P_{n+1} = 100 P_n + 12
$$
Solving we have
$$
P_n = 4 \times \frac{100^n-1}{33}
$$
Since $61$ divides $P_n$, by Fermat's theorem
$$
n = 60 k
$$
Number is clearly divisible by 3.
Working modulo $11$ we have
$$
P_{n+1} = P_n + 1
$$
So 
$$
P_1 = 1\\
P_2 = 2 \\
P_3 = 3 \\
P_4 = 4 
$$
Hence $n$ has to be a multiple of 11.

The smallest $n$ is 660.

So the number is $12$ repeated 660 times.

Comment: How do you make $61$ divide the number? I don't immediately see it. At least for divisibility by $3$ and $11$, we have the the known criterions… Never heard of one for 61. :)

Comment: Trial and error. But is better than trying out 2014 numbers, the largest having 4028 digits!

Comment: Haha well, I multiplied $61$ by $10k+2$ for $k=0, 1, 2, 3, 4, … 15$, but I haven't gotten single number of the form $121212…12$

Comment: It is 12 repeated 660 times. See my update

Comment: Finding a formula for $P_n$ is an interesting idea. Thanks for taking your time for updating the answer (+1). This is a very concrete approach to the problem!